# No logro centrar el contenido usando flexbox

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, scss

estoy intentando rehacer mi pagina con sass, para un trabajo final que tengo que entregar, y cuando intento centrar el logo y el navbar con **flexbox** no lo hace, lo estube mirando mucho y no entiendo en que me estaria equivocando, agradezco si alguno logra saber cual es el inconveniente. muchas gracias.

**HTML**

```
<header class="header">
            <a href="index.html" ><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="logotipo" class="header__logo"></a>
            <nav class="header__nav" >
                <ul>
                    <li class="select"><a href="index.html"><b>Sobre Mi</b></a></li>
                    <li><a href="conocimientos.html"><b>Conocimientos</b></a></li>
                    <li><a href="proyectos.html"><b>Proyectos</b></a></li>
                    <li><a href="experiencia.html"><b>Experiencia</b> (tabla)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contacto.html"><b>Contacto</b> (formulario)</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </header>
```

**SCSS**

```
.header{
     width: 100%;
     height: 30%;
     background-color:$celeste;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;
}

.header__logo{
    width: 30%;
}

.header__nav{
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        ul{
            margin:2vh;
            list-style: none;
            li{
                display: inline-block;
                text-decoration: none;
                padding: 3px;
                line-height: 30px;
                color:#000000;
                
                :hover{
                    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fbc2eb 0%, #a6c1ee 100%);
                    transform: rotate(4deg);
                }
                a{
                    text-decoration: none;
                    
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**HEADER**

[image: PAGINA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el header es `display: Flex;`, su contenedor debe ser `margin: auto;` para que se centre.

```
.header__logo{
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Ya probe poner en margin: auto, y no, no funciona.

Comment: Entoces agregale ```display: block;```. Con eso creo que bastaría. A mí me funciona bien. Y si aún no te funciona, tal vez tenga otro estilo que lo lo impida ya edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!! me sirvio :D